# Why can't I return a generic 'T' to satisfy a Partial<T>?

Tags: typescript, generics

I wrote some code in TypeScript:

```
type Point = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};
function getThing<T extends Point>(p: T): Partial<T> {
  // More interesting code elided
  return { x: 10 };
}
```

This produces an error:

> `Type '{ x: 10; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'`

This seems like a bug - `{ x: 10 }` is clearly a `Partial<Point>`. What's TypeScript doing wrong here? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When thinking about writing a generic function, there's an important rule to remember

## The Caller Chooses the Type Parameter

The contract you've provided for `getThing` ...

```
function getThing<T extends Point>(p: T): Partial<T>
```

... implies legal invocations like this one, where `T` is a subtype of `Point`:

```
const p: Partial<Point3D> = getThing<Point3D>({x: 1, y: 2, z: 3});
```

Of course, `{ x: 10 }` *is* a legal `Partial<Point3D>`.

But the ability to subtype doesn't just apply to adding additional properties -- subtyping can include choosing a more restricted set of the domain of the properties themselves. You might have a type like this:

```
type UnitPoint = { x: 0 | 1, y: 0 | 1 };
```

Now when you write

```
const p: UnitPoint = getThing<UnitPoint>({ x: 0, y: 1});
```

`p.x` has the value `10`, which is *not* a legal `UnitPoint`.

If you find yourself in a situation like this, odds are good that your return type *is not actually generic*. A more accurate function signature would be

```
function getThing<T extends Point>(p: T): Partial<Point> {
```

Comment: Why would someone prefer the generic signature `function getThing<T extends Point>(p: T): Partial<Point>;` to the concrete `function getThing(p: Point): Partial<Point>;`?  Excess property checks on literals?

Comment: You might write something like `<T>(x: T, y: T)`. The single-arg version doesn't make much sense but sometimes it's hard to convince people they don't really need generics

Comment: We should acknowledge the inconsistency around code like the following not triggering an error: `function getThing<T extends Point>(p: T): Partial<T> { const ret: Partial<T> = {}; ret.x = 10; return ret; }`.  TS isn't intended to be all-soundness-all-the-time, so stuff like this is inevitable, but it might be surprising.

Comment: [simple Stackblitz example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALgHgCrSQDzVQBMYB7AIwCslg0A+aAbwF8BYAKAEt0kEAzMMCTQAsqSJIQTaGk5oQSAFzQIaBNwDm0ZgG4OoSDBEBPAMpowhbLgLEj4yQ3yEUJOIlSYsDRh2j-oAHoAKmC-AOhg6GBSFFVockRleARZMBBsBixjAAdhAHJGGTkFZQAiMHJgMp1tfOhOGBRSNGhDTg0USoUZUhlcgpS0jO98gDoACgAmAGYpqYBKcICoiCQlaAALNDQciEVAwNVBAGtSADdePhBSAHcxmIBbQIBHAFckVU5YiECAFgAbABOAAcAAYAOwAmaBW6bYwAWmAYHQCM4COQaDeCBQCLACI0qF4nGACLQZNICIglkafER+JyiGGaGW-mCgVZvAQySZnHSmWgAF4mKyIrJ5Bt8pVgPlWWx2BFSCceak+RkxBIQAxhb4FREAuLStB8kqwMZZXr-PKOMwgA)