# TypeScript arguing that an interface is not compatible with generic type T, although T extends that interface

Tags: typescript, generics

I ran into a peculiar behaviour. Better explained by code below or following [this typescript playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/?target=2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFANiAnkg3gKCUKQgA8YB7AJwBckBLYaiSgMwWQCEQo74BJRszaJcBIuJiVyMAFxIQwTGMIBfPMuJkqteBihQkAdSoBrZriQbxAd1MAKAJRyuPfoNbtR470UoRqAK6UwBaS0nIARAASEGho5BFIaj6qGmoapBQ0SLrcBgBi5OQAPAAqmkzAACYGLrwCTB6IAHxeKfDkwFDUlAHw1FR2VikwAQBGaLxItpRmlHLGs8wANMM+oxNTM3MAwmNydtvMAErQAWjUcqUOSAC8rQpKKUg3OMkppBDwAUyOcihSMB0KAQMqtfDPcR+QLBJDACDWVCA4EQOx+Az3NqQ7wAehxSAAgpQAOYBSCMJDkFhIaiYGDIADkdTcjWEEAZ9AMwHItDydGJoAmyAGSDglHA-nMVJpdMZpQZADo1pD0XYaQALYEKo6UPZ2aiaqDa0zMY2zRw3BzK8TvHwqcRpPBqDpdWgsIp3OEI1AYTAKwoldBYBXMhpCdjNOzwxFBv2LOaOZZIdF3Vroq3u8gKz7fX4OBUGiDANHQVM5TpQchoCAK+LEktQBwOIA)

```
namespace Play {
    export interface BasicInterface {
        prop: any
    }

    export class Worker { 
        work(): BasicInterface {
            return { prop: "Hello" }
        }
    }

    export class Foo<T extends BasicInterface> {
        constructor(
            public worker: Worker,
            public workerCb: (workerResult: T) => any
        ) {}
        execute(): Promise<T> {
            return new Promise(res => {
                // Argument of type 'BasicInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
                res( this.workerCb(this.worker.work()) )
            }
        }    
    }
}
const foo = new Play.Foo<Play.BasicInterface>(new Play.Worker(), res => res)
foo.execute().then(res => console.log(res))
```

The problem occurs at line 20 saying that

> Argument of type 'BasicInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.

which is weird because T is defined as `T extends BasicInterface` in the Foo class declaration, so it should be fully compatible with `BasicInterface`.

So, question are: why is that and how to fix that?

*UPDATE* I'm even more puzzled now because TS seems to be fine with [this](https://typescript-play.js.org/?target=2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFANiAnkg3gKCUKQgA8YB7AJwBckBLYaiSgMwWQCEQo74BJRszaJcBIuJiVyMAFxIQwTGMIBfZcTJVa8DFChI+YGGkiMq9I2ginq+rj36DW7UeIlSYSALxIARAAkINDRyX3U1cVIKGiQdbn0AMXJyAB4AFQ0mYAATO25eASZnRAA+VzdCeHJgKGpKAFd4aioACmoACwYAc0w5NIBKXCQIojU1PGAIAHdUDEwAOiTyFsmZ9Cx5w2MbVv7+ienZjaWWnElpOV8ATSwAQl8VfqA) which is the same(-ish?) thing or I don't see how it's much different...

```
namespace Play {
    export interface BasicInterface {
        prop: any
    }
    export class Implmentor implements BasicInterface {
        prop = "Hello"
    }
    export class Foo<T extends BasicInterface> {
        constructor(thingy: T) { }
    }
}

new Play.Foo(new Play.Implmentor())
new Play.Foo({prop: "Yay!"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a correct error.

Your class's contract says that this code is legal:

```
interface BetterInterface extends Play.BasicInterface {
    thing: string;
}

const foo = new Play.Foo<BetterInterface>(new Play.Worker(), res => res)
// Throws an exception because 'thing' is undefined
foo.execute().then(res => console.log(res.thing.toUpperCase))
```

But your implementation can't produce an arbitrary `T`, it just always produces `BasicInterface`.

See also [Why can't I return a generic 'T' to satisfy a Partial<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980763/why-cant-i-return-a-generic-t-to-satisfy-a-partialt)