# Why my generic of generic doesn't work as expected?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typescript-generics

**EDIT**: a minimal example is available here [here](https://github.com/gremo/minimal-examples/tree/master/stackoverlow-57835452)

I'm using TypeScript with TypeORM library. This is the "base" `Repository` generic definition:

```js
class Repository<Entity extends ObjectLiteral> {
  find(conditions?: FindConditions<Entity>): Promise<Entity[]>;
}
```

If I try to extend this class, passing `Bank` class as `Entity`, **it works as expected** (I get auto-completion in `find` method):

```
class Bank {
  name: string;
}

class BankRepository extends Repository<Bank> {
  public test():void  {
    this.find({ name: 'foo' }); // OK!
  }
}
```

However, If I try to make *my* generic, with `BankModel` abstract class:

```
abstract class BankModel {
  foo: string;
}

class BankRepository<E extends BankModel> extends Repository<E> {
  test(foo: string): void {
    this.find({ foo: foo }); // KO!!! 
  }
}
```

The error is:

> Argument of type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindConditions'.ts(2345),

The declaration of `FindConditions<E>` is:

```
declare type FindConditions<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: FindConditions<T[P]> | FindOperator<FindConditions<T[P]>>;
};
```

So.. why it doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: I don't know typeorm so I can't reproduce this, but my hunch is that this will be something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980763/why-cant-i-return-a-generic-t-to-satisfy-a-partialt), where it is invalid to assume that `FindConditions<BankModel>` is assignable to `FindConditions<E>`  for all possible `E extends BankModel`; that is, there might be some subtype `E` of `BankModel` for which `{foo: foo}` is incompatible with `FindConditions<E>`.  If you remove the question's dependency on typeorm and post a [mcve] I might be able to answer.  Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz why it's invalid to assume that? If E extends BankModel, the public property "foo" should be there.

Comment: Did you read the linked question?

Comment: @jcalz I made a minimal example without using Typeorm library. Can you help me understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: All the code should be in the question text and not only in an external link, as described in [the guidelines for how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you do provide a link it should be to a web IDE so that others can see what's happening without having to install anything in their own environment.  I doubt anyone would be willing to `npm install` something onto their machine just to answer a question... in the ideal case, someone could drop the code into a [standalone IDE](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/Q) and reproduce.  Good luck again!

Comment: @jcalz nevermind, solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out what was a Typescript bug. I works with version 3.6.3.