# How to merge back a key with a type where the key was previously Omitted?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to implement a generic inMemoryGateway builder. I have a typing problem on the create implementation: I want to be able to give an entity without the 'id' (using typescript Omit) and than to add the missing 'id'. But the types don't seem compatibles. I used `as any` for now but anyone would see a cleaner solution ?

```
interface EntityGateway<E extends {id: string}> {
  create: (entity: Omit<E, 'id'>) => E
  getAll: () => E[]
}

const buildInMemoryGateway = <Entity extends {id: string}>(): EntityGateway<Entity> => {
  const entities: Entity[] = [];

  return {
    create: (entityWithoutId: Omit<Entity, 'id'>) => {
      const entity: Entity = { ...entityWithoutId, id: 'someUuid' }
      // Error here on entity : 
      // Type 'Pick<Entity, Exclude<keyof Entity, "id">> & { id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Entity'.
      // ugly fix: const entity: Entity = { ...entityWithoutId as any, id: 'someUuid' }

      entities.push(entity);
      return entity
    },
    getAll: () => {
      return entities;
    }
  }
}



interface Person {
  id: string,
  firstName: string,
  age: number,
}

const personGateway = buildInMemoryGateway<Person>();

personGateway.create({ age: 35, firstName: 'Paul' });   // OK as expected
personGateway.create({ age: 23, whatever: 'Charlie' }); // error as expected

console.log("Result : ", personGateway.getAll())
```

Comment: What do you expect to see with `interface OnlyAlice { id: "Alice" }; const g = buildInMemoryGateway<OnlyAlice>(); g.create({}); g.getAll()[0].id`?

Comment: I would expect to get 'someUuid', but it is a usage I wouldn't have...

Comment: But the type of that value is `"Alice"` in the type system.  What you are doing isn't safe, because `Omit<E, "id"> & {id: string}` isn't necessarily the same as `E` even if `E extends {id: string}`.  That's why the compiler is warning you.  If you don't expect that `id` will ever be a string literal type, then use a type assertion as you're doing and move on.  Otherwise there are ways to make it type safe, but it's ugly, as you have to drag types like `Omit<E, "id"> & {id: string}` around where previously you'd be using `E`.

Comment: The issue is essentially the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980763/why-cant-i-return-a-generic-t-to-satisfy-a-partialt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980763/why-cant-i-return-a-generic-t-to-satisfy-a-partialt) about assigning a value to a `Partial<T>` when `T` is a generic parameter extending some known object type `U`.  You can't just return a value of type `Partial<U>`, because when `T extends U` it could do so by adding new properties to `U` (no problem), or by *narrowing* the existing properties of `T` (uh oh!).  And since in a generic function the *caller* chooses the type parameter, the implementation cannot guarantee that properties of `T` won't be narrower in type than the corresponding properties of `U`.

That leads to this problem:

```
interface OnlyAlice { id: "Alice" };
const g = buildInMemoryGateway<OnlyAlice>();
g.create({});
g.getAll()[0].id // "Alice" at compile time, "someUuid" at runtime.  Uh oh!
```

If you wanted to rewrite your code safely, you could do so by making the code less readable and more complex, by keeping the actual type you've created: not `E`, but `Omit<E, "id"> & {id: string}`.  That is always true, even if the original `E` has a narrower type for its `id` property:

```
type Stripped<E> = Omit<E, "id">;
type Entity<E> = Stripped<E> & { id: string };

interface EntityGateway<E> {
    create: (entity: Stripped<E>) => Entity<E>
    getAll: () => Entity<E>[]
}

const buildInMemoryGateway = <E>(): EntityGateway<E> => {
    const entities: Entity<E>[] = [];
    return {
        create: (entityWithoutId: Stripped<E>) => {
            const entity = { ...entityWithoutId, id: 'someUuid' }
            entities.push(entity);
            return entity
        },
        getAll: () => {
            return entities;
        }
    }
}
```

And that behaves the same for your examples:

```
interface Person {
    id: string,
    firstName: string,
    age: number,
}

const personGateway = buildInMemoryGateway<Person>();

personGateway.create({ age: 35, firstName: 'Paul' });   // OK as expected
personGateway.create({ age: 23, whatever: 'Charlie' }); // error as expected
```

But now it behaves differently for the pathological example above:

```
interface OnlyAlice { id: "Alice" };
const g = buildInMemoryGateway<OnlyAlice>();
g.create({});
g.getAll()[0].id // string at compile time, "someUuid" at run time, okay!
```

---

If you read that and said to yourself, "oh come on, nobody's going to narrow the `id` property to a string literal", that's fair.  But it means you need to use something like a type assertion, as you saw:

```
 const entity = { ...entityWithoutId, id: 'someUuid' } as E; // assert
```

You *might* expect that the compiler could see this as acceptable:

```
 const entity: E = { ...entityWithoutId, id: 'someUuid' as E["string"]}; // error!
```

but that doesn't work because the compiler doesn't really bother trying to analyze the intersection of an unresolved conditional type like `Omit<E, "id">`.  There's a [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#issuecomment-448356158) to address that but for now you need a type assertion.

---

Anyway I'd expect the way you want to go here is to use a type assertion, but hopefully the explanation above shows what the compiler is doing.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlEAzCBBYATAqgOYA2AnkgN4CwAUEvUgC6kzIqMBOAljK7gDwBRAHxIAvEgDyYLoyEAaJACIuuJcIDctBkxbJBwRrNJDRE9t14QBIpADJKSVQC4kUTl2CEkAXy01tBk9GCA50BH1DYwBxEBCAdxATW2o6HQZ4Dgg4iFcACggo5lcLHj5TAEpxUQMjZlNA9KRCCEYsYmJ8qrEaouThAG0AXUbfWlH4AHtgdyQAIwBXLmJcAElgAFkIMEmOUliEpPEkUzyK11qYnMT+6spRnSmZxiRCuq5oC77TYePh-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)