# Issues using Partial<T> on a bounded generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
function f<T extends {id: string}>(id: T['id']): Partial<T> {
  return {id: id}; // ERROR: Type '{ id: T["id"]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'
}
```

([TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEBvGAgLkSKgCcYwBzAXwD4AKC6tAbQHIK-ALoBKagAUAhnVhSANujZkAUIkR1MUEHSTkqiCiwDciAPRnEAUQBKNgPI2eATwAOmRP1KGDfAEQUfsKmLPyGJGBwUIhSREQwTGBSAEbyHlBwiFBuHvzSsjAKSvwqLEA))

I'm trying to figure out why the above code isn't allowed.  Is is fundamentally unsound?  Or is it because of a limitation of the TypeScript type system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a missing feature; the compiler can't see the assignment as sound and rejects it for the same reason as in [Why can't I return a generic 'T' to satisfy a Partial<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46980763/288721), even though it would be safe to allow it.  There was an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#22229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22229) asking for it to be addressed, but it was closed as "working as intended".  From the discussion within it looks like it's just a missing feature or a design limitation.

You could, if you want, use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function fAssert<T extends {id: string}>(id: T['id']): Partial<T> {
  return {id: id} as Partial<T>; // assert
}
```

Or you could build the return value in stages (although this method is too permissive and allows [some unsound things](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30989) which probably won't be fixed anytime soon either):

```
function fRoundabout<T extends {id: string}>(id: T['id']): Partial<T> {
  const ret: Partial<T> = {}; // allowed
  ret.id = id; // also works
  return ret;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure why you want the return type to be `Partial<T>`, though, since such a type may or may not have values at the keys of `T`, whereas your returned object definitely has an `id` property and nothing else.  It looks more like `Pick<T, "id">` than `Partial<T>` to me:

```
function fDifferentReturnType<T extends { id: string }>(id: T['id']): Pick<T, 'id'> {
  return { id: id }; // okay
}
```

Since the example is just a toy example, it's quite possible that your real use case requires `Partial<T>` and not `{id: T['id']}`. But if not, then you might decide to sidestep the whole `Partial` issue entirely.

Okay, hopefully one of those suggestions helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAggZzQUwE5QDwAqimAHlJmACZqIDeiMlAXImlNjGAOaIC+AfAApGLAgG0A5IwkBdAJQsACgENcMZQBtC-OgChEibJighsSeiIaU+iZTRVrN2gNyIA9G9sYcUXb126oJCwCMgASnDglMoARpH4RKTkVDQWzKzsnDwCwuniUpSyCogOsE4EOrT6iBAIbIbGSqplWhWIALx0vK4ethoacADumJTVRlAAdIwdVj2emmhwiINw2ADWaGPGpkjjzn6IAYHg0PBIwAAiMMDAOBRQYdtmBACeAA6YhMRkFNR0Viw2BxuHwhJZ8tJ5EoYBA1oQADSIAoSSpbExmf6WabddyeOBrZQvPxAA)

Comment: I think we need the Partial<T>.  We're currently using a type assertion to shut the type checker up :-)

I was planning on reporting a bug but first wanted to confirm that I wasn't doing something unsound (which can sometimes be sutble).  Thanks for the link to the existing bug report; I've included it in a comment near the type assertion in our code.

Answer (score 1):

[jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63553942/8634147) suggest 3 options. Which one fits?

I agree with him in the fact that it's not clear from this "toy" example if there's a true need to want the return type `Partial<T>`. `Pick<T, 'id'>` can be enough. In this case, inference just work fine and it may be a simpler solution:

```
function f<T extends {id: string}>(id: T['id']) {
  return { id }; // type: { id: T['id'] }
}
```