# Value not assignable to type 'Partial' when using interface extends with generic types

Tags: typescript

Observe the following:

```
class Table<ValuesType extends DefaultTableValues = DefaultTableValues>{
    public values: ValuesType;
    constructor(initialValues:ValuesType) {
        this.values=initialValues;
    }

    public set(newValues:Partial<ValuesType>){
        this.values={
            ...this.values,
            ...newValues
        }
    }
}

class User<MoreValues extends UserValues = UserValues> extends Table<MoreValues>{
    constructor(values:MoreValues) {
        super(values);

        this.set({avatar:'some-string'});
        //ERROR - Argument of type {avatar:'some-string'} is not assignable to type Partial
    }
}
interface DefaultTableValues{
    id:string;
}
interface UserValues extends DefaultTableValues{
    avatar:string;
    username:string;
}
```

I get the following error with `this.set`:
`Argument of type {avatar:'some-string'} is not assignable to type Partial`

If I change `class User<MoreValues extends UserValues = UserValues> extends Table<MoreValues>` to `class User extends Table<UserValues>` then it works, but I lose the ability to pass specific User types and extend the `User` class.

Shouldn't `MoreValues` always have the `avatar:string` property since it extends `UserValues`?

I have a feeling this is somehow related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980763/why-cant-i-return-a-generic-t-to-satisfy-a-partialt) but I can't figure out how to apply a fix to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the issue is the same in the question you linked. Per said question's accepted answer:

> But the ability to subtype doesn't just apply to adding additional properties -- subtyping can include choosing a more restricted set of the domain of the properties themselves.

For example, assume the following interface:

```
interface RestrictedValues extends UserValues {
    avatar: "nonexistent"
}
```

This interface does extend `UserValues`, and is thus assignable to `MoreValues`. However, its `avatar` property can only have the value `nonexistent`, so the `Partial<>` which is `set()`'s first argument should only allow the value `nonexistent`, not any string as `UserValues` would imply. Take, for example, the following code:

```
class User<MoreValues extends UserValues = UserValues> extends Table<MoreValues>{
    constructor(values:MoreValues) {
        super(values);

        const thing1: RestrictedValues = { avatar: "nonexistent", id: "", username: "" };
        const thing2: MoreValues = thing1;
    }
}
```

In this, `thing1` cannot be assigned to `thing2`, since it is not guaranteed that `MoreValues` will not instantiated with, say, `{ avatar: "" }`, where the only accepted value is an empty string, to which `"nonexistent"` is not assignable. Therefore, TypeScript throws the error:

```
Type 'RestrictedValues' is not assignable to type 'MoreValues'.
  'RestrictedValues' is assignable to the constraint of type 'MoreValues', but 'MoreValues' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'UserValues'.
```

A simpler example of this is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701587/16121252), using only booleans, which I recommend reading if you want to better understand the logic behind this behaviour.

> That error is warning you, that your Generic Type `P` can't be
> assigned to `{}`, since the Generic Type `P` can be a more defined, or
> restricted, to a particular type that can conflict with the default
> value.
>
> That means that the value `{}` can't satisfy all the possible Types
> that can be used by the Generic Type `P`.
>
> Let's create another example with only booleans that should be easier
> to understand:
>
> ```
> interface OnlyBoolIdentityInterface<T> {
>   (arg: T): T;
> }
>
> function onlyBoolGeneric<T extends boolean>(arg: T = false): T {
>   return arg;
> }
> ```
>
> if you define a Type that is more specific than a boolean for example:
>
> ```
> type TrueType = true;
> ```
>
> and if you specialised the function `OnlyBoolIdentityInterface` to
> only support true values like this:
>
> ```
> const onlyTrueIdentity: OnlyBoolIdentityInterface<TrueType> = onlyBoolGeneric;
> ```
>
> even if TrueType respects the constraint set by `T extends boolean`
> the default value `arg: T = false` is not a `TrueType`.
>
> This is the situation is what the error is trying to convey to you.
>
> So how can you fix this type of errors?
>
> 1. Or you remove the default value
> 2. Or T needs to extend the specialised type of the default param that on my example is false
> 3. Or T can interfere directly with params that receive default params
>
> For more context about this error message see the issue that suggested
> this error message
> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29049.