# Type X is not assignable to type Y (mapped type)

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the Typescript error

```
Type '{ aaa: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; }'.ts(2322)
```

related to the `const c` in the following code

```
class MyClass<T extends { aaa: string }> {
    public find(aaa: string) {
        const c: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] } = { aaa };
    }
}
```

I've looked through many stack overflow posts that don't seem to help because I think this is particularly related to the mapped type.

I would expect that the mapped type defined above would let me use properties defined in the type constraint `{ aaa: string }`.

Is that not true? Is there something about type contraints that aren't enumerable over mapped types?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Weird. Same behaviour when using `Partial`. Which is is the same as your definition but still, I had to check. Also, while it doesn't allow direct assignment, TS is fine with `c.aaa = aaa;` : [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGAb2jCoC5oI8AnAS0IHNoBfAPmjIChog6AAcArgCMQTYNABmLYgAoqYWvWZsAlLwFC9wAPaF60YLQoBtAArQW0ANZZ4B2dHQBdAPy101952gAXl5OAG4+XT1BYAA6FSDKKnC9Dj4OIA)

Comment: I expected it to be because `T` might be `{ aaa: "literal string type"; }` like this: `const x = new MyClass<{ aaa: "example"; }>();`, and then `{ aaa: string; }` isn't assignable to that. But the fix I thought would fix that (`find(aaa: T["aaa"])`) doesn't fix it, so there goes my theory...

Comment: @VLAZ - Excess property checks? Even though all the properties in the type of `c` are optional? No, that probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Excess property checks usually come with a different message. However, given that it's showing up in assignment to a literal - maybe? Could be some weird bug with excess property checks over a mapped type that triggers an incorrect error.

Comment: The compiler's not great about higher order type operations but in this case it's right to complain; you can write `const n = new MyClass<{ aaa: "hello" }>().find("goodbye");` and suddenly you're claiming that `{aaa: "goodbye"}` is assignable to `{aaa?: "hello"}`, which it isn't. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mMMVkm).  As such I think this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980763/why-cant-i-return-a-generic-t-to-satisfy-a-partialt .  Anyone disagree?

Comment: @jcalz no disagreement. That question seems to be spot-on.