# TypeScript can't use keyof generic parameter as a key of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a generic function that gets a parameter with the type of `keyof T` and creates a `Partial` object using that parameter.

This code below generates an error: Type '{ [x: string]: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial':

```
const notWorkingPk = <T>(pk: keyof T): Partial<T> => {
    const condition: Partial<T> = {
        [pk]: undefined
    };
};
```

However, that code works just fine:

```
const workingPk = <T>(pk: keyof T): void => {
    const condition: Partial<T> = {};

    condition[pk] = undefined;
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBGJQOogE4GsCWYDmAFNMAvDADwAqAfABQAOaAXDGgKYCeIAZjGQJREUwA3gCgYYmKEixJAEwxQM4RrgCGKBSoA25AcRHiDMANp0AuowCuYGcw5ZmM0eIC%20AbmHPhwydBgB3VEwcfCJSSloGJjZObj5CAX1xH2lwOQUlGFV1DC0dUME3LwNZeUUwEzRTUKsbOzAHd08vIA)

My question is, why, and is there a way to write the code in the first way?

Comment: even `const notWorkingPk = <K extends 1>(pk: K) => {
    const condition = {
        [pk]: undefined
    };
}` will be `const condition: {
    [x: number]: undefined;
}`, @jcalz plz paste your comment an TS being bad with `{ [key]: whatever }` (was there one? iirc there was)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker cannot really accurately determine when a specific value is or is not assignable to a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type.  There are a very few operations on generics that TypeScript can "reason" about properly. For most operations, it either treats the generic type as *opaque* and is unable to see any non-identical type as being assignable, or it gives up and replaces the generic type parameters with their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  In the former case this is very strict and can lead to false positives (errors on safe code), while the latter end up being too lax and lead to false negatives (failure to error on unsafe code).

---

The former situation is what happens with

```
const condition: Partial<T> = {
    [pk]: undefined
}; // error!
```

The compiler treats `Partial<T>` as mostly opaque and doesn't accept `{[pk]: undefined}` as a possible value, even though `undefined` should be allowed as a value of any property of `Partial<T>` for any `T` (assuming you have not enabled [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), that is).  Indeed if you change `T` to some specific type, then the assignment will succeed.  But the compiler is unable to reason that `undefined` is allowed for the generic case.  This is as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#22229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22229).  If you want the compiler to accept that, you should use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const condition = {
    [pk]: undefined
}  as Partial<T>;
```

---

The latter situation is what happens with

```
const condition: Partial<T> = {};
condition[pk] = undefined;
```

The compiler treats `{}` as one of the few valid types assignable to `Partial<T>` for generic `T` (this had to be explicitly implemented), and then when you assign to `condition[pk]` the compiler is lax and allows `undefined` to be assigned.  This happens to be safe, but the compiler isn't really checking it properly.

This is as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30989](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30989).  A similar situation happens here:

```
const compare = <T extends {a: string}>(s: string) => {   
    const p: Partial<T> = {a: s}; // error

    const o: Partial<T> = {};
    o.a = s; // okay
}
```

The `p` line gives an error while the `o` code accepts it, but in this case it is the error that's correct, because maybe `T` will be specified with a type like `{a: "x" | "y"}` and calling `compare<{a: "x" | "y"}>("z")` will end up trying to assign `"z"` to a place that should be `"x" | "y"`.  See [Why can't I return a generic 'T' to satisfy a Partial<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46980763/2887218) for more information about that.

---

So that's what's going on.  The compiler can't really do accurate analysis on arbitrary generic operations, so it takes shortcuts.  If it complains about something you know to be safe, you can use a type assertion to suppress it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBGJQOogE4GsCWYDmAFNMAvDADwAqAfABQAOaAXDGgKYCeIAZjGQJREUwA3gCgYYmKEixJAEwxQM4RrgCGKBSoA25AcRHiDMANp0AuowCuYGcw5ZmM0eIC+MFRBir1GLToDcws7CwpLQMADuqJg4+ESklLQMTGyc3HyEAvriodLgcgpKnmoa2pRxgs4BBrLyimAmaKZxVjZ2YA4BQcE5EiAAtjRqzHHkMMwAHlDM1h6CbozQKFjYMM7UEAtQSzjpmU5iPTTKxT6lukLzMB6VMAD0t2MoKKjB1eBhIMfevmV6lfswEAAOhUcQgfjuDxAaBUrEC3X6gxQzBIcxUjAAROMMTAAD4wDGsHFrKgYgBeGJ4EPugJANAgQA)