# How to write a type safe generic closure with assigned properties on the returned function

Tags: typescript

I was hoping to be able to write a type safe memoize function that supports taking a generic function, and also supports clearing the internal cache via an assigned property on the returned function, like so:

```
const memoizeSafeButLosesGenerics = <Args extends unknown[], RV>(fn: (...args: Args) => RV) => {
    const cache = new Map<string, RV>();
    const memoed = (...args: Args): RV => {
        // implementation here...
        
        return fn(...args);
    };
    memoed.clear = () => cache.clear();
    return memoed;
};
```

Unfortunately, when I test this out, TypeScript does not preserve generic type parameters on a provided `fn`:

```
const test1 = memoizeSafeButLosesGenerics(<T,>(t: T) => t);
// test1 is:
// {
//     (t: unknown): unknown;
//     clear(): void;
// }
```

It is worth noting that removing the second to last line (where `memoed.clear` is assigned) *does* preserve the generic type parameter, so I suppose something about that assignment changes the type of `memoed` as it relates to its inference.

There is a workaround that preserves generic type parameters, however, it requires type assertions and allows one to do unsafe things in the memoize function's implementation. For example:

```
const memoizeUnsafePreservesGenericsWorkaround = <Fn extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>(fn: Fn) => {
    type RV = ReturnType<Fn>;
    const cache = new Map<string, RV>();
    type UnsafeExampleArgs = Parameters<Fn> | [] | null[];
    const memoed = ((...args: UnsafeExampleArgs): RV => {
        // implementation here...

        // I would expect UnsafeExampleArgs to _not_ be valid arguments to fn
        return fn(...args); // I would expect calling fn _would_ be a valid RV
    }) as Fn;
    const memoedClearable = Object.assign(memoed, {
        clear: () => cache.clear()
    });
    return memoedClearable;
};

const test2 = memoizeUnsafePreservesGenericsWorkaround(<T,>(t: T) => t);
// test2 is ✅:
// (<T>(t: T) => T) & {
//     clear: () => void;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUziAlgLwQZQIYDMEBCArlADIgQIQDiCYCATisBDALwwA8AggwOasEADyh0AJqyJgA1mBAB3MAG0AugBoYAJQBqAPgAUuMAC4Y%20gHSXs-CKd4CAlO11btTti4DeAKBh%20YoJCwwNjAABYI7DD08jAAstgADpzQTGB8GjoGDgDcvv6B0PBIIAhiURZWNnY2DqY6zjA%20-i0wAPRtMChwiQA2SHRQ2FAo4DARDAiW5t75rTCTUEQMYDBGlebWjnktAL47-ojIZebA-dYV7i4h4VNnCNb6uXMLCEsrxcdiefuzhbCiaAARiiR1QGBw%20GIZAoVFo9CYLH0nAAKmoDFBTCirjAoM8OriqFAQShbN4CT4CS19JiYFJZAowHU6TI5Io8lSCucGE9TAA3VDfcmdXZ-cBFMHoBAAVUgeAQAAVJpQGHy4XRGMwIAB1EAMaTWEBScocTgAMVWwlEYAkZmmW1sLIZilUOPpbLABiMpgtOOa-igAE9EpEGhxNG9lmAUcGEObPQc-P8AqEIlEYvEkikoGkMq5soncbGYLKIPKAKJCbA9fr2VgcBXWatvRgQeMuAA%20MFUMC7YCIvV6qkLybBZQqGwdplLFarNYQdeZYa8LxaBO6fQGYCGIzGEymllm8z8BIAkjB5EbeuVhCHgLAZ-hK9XN3XcSAYAB9ORQT8wABGkR8tgvQoOUWxEIg26sFAH5GKu-iLFGaxgJOtQ5O0nTnpeA43kId7BCBoHpChX44def6ATA2AwMBoHlDoLy7E42CsBaI7irAY5iAAwty2D-v0UQAPL-gAVgg96bBAEAoHwqHcRo-rzPc1imE8jQ3BEpzck8THPC0SEfNxfEPAwAn9D8eTeMmgJQAATKCJRSo%20irKowao0BqiI6nqBoMEaNrImiGJYjieIcp0dmOaSMCAKDkxjCmYqKhTA2KNOlABkTRJS0qkMOpOICmBkUwLsQA)

Is there a third alternative way to write memoize in such a way where the provided function's generic type parameters are preserved that does *not* involve type assertions in memoize's implementation?

Comment: The support for preserving generics safely is implemented in [ms/TS#30215](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) but it's fragile, you can't add props. Your workaround to just copy the function type directly is unsafe by definition because, maybe, the function *input* has extra properties. (e.g., `memoize(Object.assign(()=>{}, {x: 0})` claims to return something with an `x` prop but it's not there.) So you'll need to choose which drawback to live with, until and unless more higher-order func support is implemented. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for the response. I hadn't thought of the "input extra property" case so thank you for pointing that out. Yes, that does answer the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to type `memoize()` such that both callers and the implementation see the behavior you want.  You'll have to choose one or the other.

---

Your `memoizeSafeButLosesGenerics()` is trying to use the [support for higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215), but unfortunately this is support is very fragile and only works if the output is directly another function type without other structure.  So returning `(...a: A) => R` is fine, and you'll get a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function out if you pass one in. But if you try to add properties to the return type (e.g., `{ (...a: A): R; x: string }`) or put the function inside some container type (e.g., `{ func: (...a: A) => R }`) or just about any other modification, the higher order inference fails, and any generic function you pass in gets its type parameters *erased*, and subtituted with their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints). You can read microsoft/TypeScript#30215 to see the exact conditions during which the inference works.  It's fairly limited.

---

Your workaround in `memoizeUnsafePreservesGenericsWorkaround()` just copies the whole input function type directly, which preserves everything, including generic type parameters.  Unfortunately this is unsafe by definition, because you really can't guarantee that a manually crafted function will be of a given *generic* type *constrained* to a function type, even if they have the same input and output types.  For example, your input function could itself have more properties, such as

```
const f = memoizeUnsafePreservesGenericsWorkaround(
  Object.assign(() => { }, { x: 0 })
);
/* const f: (() => void) & {
    x: number;
} & {
    clear: () => void;
}*/

f.x.toFixed(2) // RUNTIME ERROR!
```

And then `memoizeUnsafePreservesGenericsWorkaround` claims that the output has an `x` property, which it doesn't.
You can try to patch holes like this in the implementation, if you are likely to actually see them in practice (you probably won't), but the compiler is hopelessly unable to see what you're doing as safe and you'll end up needing [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which is what you're trying to avoid.  It doesn't even really try, and will usually just refuse to accept any value as being assignable to a generic type unless that value is already known to be of the exact type.  It's the same general situation as in [Why can't I return a generic 'T' to satisfy a Partial<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46980763/2887218).

Furthermore, sometimes inside a generic function, the compiler will widen a type parameter to its constraint and allow unsafe things to happen.  Generic function implementations that do anything outside of a few simple well-understood operation will almost always need to be careful and convince yourself that your code is going to work, because the type checker isn't as useful as you'd like.

---

So, there you go. Personally I'd recommend finding behavior you think is best for callers, and then just deal with the drawbacks for the implementer.  Functions are generally implemented once and called many times, so any burden of needing to second-guess the type checker is probably better placed on the implementer and not all the possible callers.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-oQeTteSxbtgeAS8fQWA+RFI5CotHojGYbE43D4ghU+WDYYjTujsaeWeBMDtSZgsn0AAYV9YAqWwQAqS5FMUZzNAyioAS2ABkwIlG5gxzgnOIDZgd+TwQL3AzS8vfINgeYJYngaiyGo9ISCgsj3CoABMtiqtEmAAHJpLitRjDAYzRNEgbRAAhEAA)